# Thunderbolt 3 external drive not showing up in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: thunderbolt, ubuntu-20.04, lacie

I have Ubuntu 20.04
I try to add a Direct Attached Storage (DAS) to my Ubuntu machine via a Thunderbolt 3 slot.

The DAS is an "2big Dock Thunderbolt 3 from Lacie". 
Via USB it works. 
Via "Thunderbolt 3" it is recognized under `Devices > Thunderbolt`

But I can not access the disk. 
How can I make Ubuntu mount the disk?

Answer (score 1):

What helped was

- disable "Security" for Thunderbolt BIOS by 
  Setting it in `BIOS> Advanced > Chipset Configuration > Intel Thunderbolt`
   to "No Security"
- setting the Thunderbolt mode to "BIOS Assist"

After it is listed under Disks on the picture

[image]